# Passing an array as an argument in a function

Tags: c, arrays

I have initialised an array of integers which i later call in a function. I noticed that the values have changed. What can i do to stop that from happening?

```
void check(int arr[5][6]){
    printf("%s", arr[0][0]);
}

int main(){
    int arr[5][6];
    arr[0][0] = 5;
    check(arr);
}
```

Comment: `%d` or `%i` is the format specifier for `int`s, not `%s`.

Comment: Per Ryan's comment, if you had compiled with `-Wall`, the compiler would have flagged your `printf` as a mismatch. Also, be sure you're doing `#include <stdio.h>`

Answer (score 3):

You're not using the correct format specifier to `printf`.

To print an `int`, you need to use the `%d` format specifier.  You're using `%s`, which expects a pointer to a null terminated string.

```
printf("%d", arr[0][0]);
```

Using the incorrect format specifier leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 0):

The value stored in the array at `(0,0)` has not changed. Even, if you have passed it to a function. What's wrong in your program is the way you are expecting `printf` to print an element of the two dimensional array which is of `int` data type.

Since `array` is a two dimensional array of data type `int`. An element stored at `arr[0][0]` will be of `int` data type.

So, you need to change your program to:

```
void check(int arr[5][6])
{
    printf("%d", arr[0][0]);
}

int main()
{
   int arr[5][6];
   arr[0][0] = 5;
   check(arr);
}
```

The code you have posted will have undefined behavior. The code you have pasted will give warning. Have a look at the warning that i have got by compiling your code with gcc.

> warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
>            printf("%s", arr[0][0]);

**Remember: You should never ignore warning.**

You have used `"%s"` format specifier which assumes a pointer to a character array in the arguments list. You just need to change it to `"%d"`.

There are many format specifiers in c. Few are given below-

```
%c - For Character Variable
%d - For Integers
%f - For Double
%s - For Null-Terminated Character Array
%p - For Pointers (of void * type)
```

Comment: Better to say "%d" for `int` rather than "integers".  "integers" as discussed in the C spec, refer to `char, short, unsigned long, intmax_t` as well as many others.  Similar issues with the others  (except `%p - For Pointers (of void * type)` which is fine.)